# Count/plot changes over time for a variable in panel data with R

Tags: r, panel-data

I'm relatively new to R and got stuck with an actually simple thing. I have panel data and I want to plot or count how many observation units experience a change in a specific variable over time. The data looks the following way:

```
statename,from,to,id,x
United States,1946,1965,201000,
United States,1946,1965,202000,
United States,1946,1965,203000,false
United States,1970,1973,203000,true
United States,1946,1965,204000,
United States,1946,1965,205000,true
```

So, to be precise, I want to get a number of how many `ids` experienced a change in `x` and/or how many always had `true` for `x` and how many always had `false` for `x`.

I tried to make a dummy that equals 1 if `x` was `true` at least once and `false` at least once, i.e., if there was a change. However, it did not work. I also tried to approach the problem with the `table()`, `aggregate()`, `group_by()` and `count()` functions (partly combined) but I just do not get what I want.

Can anybody possibly help?

Comment: What is your expected output? A plot? or are you looking for a table? I am unclear. Could you provide a sample output?

Answer (score 1):

To make it reproducible:

```
my_data <- read.csv(text=
"statename,from,to,id,x
United States,1946,1965,201000,
United States,1946,1965,202000,
United States,1946,1965,203000,false
United States,1970,1973,203000,true
United States,1946,1965,204000,
United States,1946,1965,205000,true", header=TRUE)
```

Here is a solution using package `dplyr` and functions `mutate()` and `lag()`:

```
library(dplyr)
my_data <- my_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(xChanged = case_when(x != lag(x) ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ "No")) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Step-by-step, here is what the code above does:

1. It groups your data by `id`.
2. It then uses the `lag()` function to look up the previous value of `x`.
3. If `x` is different from the previous `x`, it inputs "Yes" to column `xChanged` .
4. Otherwise, it inputs "No" to column `xChanged`

The output will look like this:

```
> my_data
      statename from   to     id     x xChanged
1 United States 1946 1965 201000             No
2 United States 1946 1965 202000             No
3 United States 1946 1965 203000 false       No
4 United States 1970 1973 203000  true      Yes
5 United States 1946 1965 204000             No
6 United States 1946 1965 205000  true       No
```

Now you can count how many "Yes" there are in `xChanged`.

```
nrow(my_data[my_data$xChanged == "Yes",])
```

Result: 1.